# Create upload URL using blobstore.create_upload_url()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In my GAE app when the request page is **appid.appspot.com/module?action=form** using the code snippet below I am getting this ouput **appid.appspot.com/_ah/upload/?action=form/fu6YsSdQIK6rzh9e3Q6t...fu6YsSdQIK6rzh9e3Q6t/**

```
blobstore.create_upload_url('module/')
```

The URL I want to create should be like this

```
appid.appspot.com/module/_ah/upload/fu6YsSdQIK6rzh9e3Q6t...fu6YsSdQIK6rzh9e3Q6t?action=edit
```

Is there a standard way to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

No, you have not read the documentation. You don't get to control the upload URL: the parameter you pass is where the browser gets redirected to *after* the upload. The upload destination is controlled by GAE itself and cannot be changed from your code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I do understand that I can't control the upload URL. I am concerned about the redirected URL which contains the request page query string "?action=form". I don't want this part to be added to URL automatically. Instead I want my own query string "?action=edit"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my deployment. I don't know why it started happening with that setup beyond the fact that I was using a custom domain on the app (and removing it had no effect). In the end, though, it didn't seem to affect anything. Once I had my permissions set up right (oops) uploads worked fine despite the wonky URL.